# Pentaho CE stack deployment from test to production environment

Tags: deployment, pentaho, kettle

I have a task to find out a way to deploy Pentaho BI CE server, Kettle jobs/transformation from testing to production environment servers.

It is pretty clear how to deploy Pentaho BI server, but the problem is that I do not have clear understanding how can I transfer all my data (Schemas, CDE dashboards, Saiku queries etc.) from one environment to another. Should I download all data and just upload to production server? But that does not seems to be viable solution.

For Kettle jobs/transformation the best approach would be to use repositories, but I still can not figure it out how it could be moved from testing to prod environments.

So my question is - what is the best approach to deploy Pentaho to different environments?

P.S. I am still very new to Pentaho and all BI stuff, so if I made some technical mistakes, please correct me.

Comment: For Kettle stuff, have you seen the two answers posted here: [Migrating Transformations in Pentaho](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218605/migrating-transformations-in-pentaho-pdi/33220184#33220184)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download/Upload is the usual procedure. You can also take a look at the Repository Synchronizer in the marketplace. That might be helpful to ease part of the work.